# Does blender have the concept of instances and params?

Tags: materials, instances

### Goal

My goal is to keep a single source of truth while allowing instances to modify a few expected parameters (a material for example).

This way I can create a small object in a separate file, and create instances of it in many different files. Each instance would allow me to override a param from its default value for the material.

If I ever need to change all objects of that type, I'd just modify the main one.

It's a bit similar to Object-Oriented Programming, but using Blender objects instead.

Unreal Engine 4 has exactly this concept that I'm looking for when it comes to materials: https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Rendering/Materials/MaterialInstances/

Does Blender Cycles have this concept of params for materials? Does it also have the concept of instances?

### Example

**File: Ball.blend**

1. Created a Sphere called Ball.
2. Apply a simple diffuse material. By default the color is **red**. Instances of Ball should be able to choose a different color, so I want to create a param called 'color' for the material.

**File: Beach.blend**

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to *Link* Ball into this file. Any changes made in the original Ball will be reflected here.
2. I want to change the color of the ball to **green**, so I override the param 'color' to 'green'.

I could decide later that all balls should be glossy, so I could apply this shader to the main material and all balls are now glossy while maintaining the **green** color for my instance since I'm expecting a parameter in the material called 'color'.

Comment: There are instances, and you can link them from other files, what we currently lack is a clean way to provide material overrides; for groups in an easy way at least; using scripting it may be doable. For individual objects libraries you can easily override materials using built-in tools. Improvements in that area are planned for the upcoming new version 2.8

Comment: You are looking for [drivers](https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/drivers/introduction.html). As I just saw it in another question have a look at the [CGCookie flexrig](https://cgcookie.com/resource/cg-cookie-flex-rig/) - the ui part of the rig lets you change colours in the materials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be accomplished with [Node Groups](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/node_editor/nodes/groups.html).

> Grouping nodes can simplify a node tree by allowing instancing and hiding parts of the tree. Both material and composite nodes can be grouped.
>
> Also nested node groups are supported. I.e. a node group can be inserted or created inside another node group.

For example, creating a 'GlossyMaterial' shader group with an input for color. Node Groups can be linked/appended across files and shared between many material instances.

Further resources:

- [Introduction to Node Groups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=57YjX3nfb8Q)