# Can Node Frames be saved for recall later?

Tags: node-editor

Can Node Frames be saved for recall later maybe in another project? Are they (frames) managed as object data in and of their own right?

Comment: No, frames are not datablocks, use NodeGroups instead

Comment: Thanks is this in 2.79 too? (Couldn't find it in the manual) [link]https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/texture_node/types/groups.html[link]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93659/how-to-link-a-variable-of-a-material-to-another-material/93661#93661 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68328/does-blender-have-the-concept-of-instances-and-params/72592#72592 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7826/can-i-make-a-custom-node-from-a-group-and-have-that-available-in-other-projects/7830#7830 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7826/can-i-make-a-custom-node-from-a-group-and-have-that-available-in-other-projects/7830#7830

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32984/is-there-a-way-to-save-composite-node-presets/32985#32985